# Change table header with rows on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am not a good designer, please bear with these illustrations.

I have table something like this

[image]

but when we resize or on mobile screens, table should change into :

[image]

Please guide

Comment: Did you try anything???

Comment: Yes @GuruprasadRao , actually I only know about how to implement the responsive table with some scroll features etc. but don't know how to implement this feature. I am new to bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

[image: Bootstrap grid]

These are the Bootstrap classes to add to each of your table rows in order to generate your desired layout on mobile. You will need to make sure yu have the proper bootstrap js and css files for this to work. You can get these from the bootstrap website as well as tutorials on how the bootstrap grid works.

```
<table class="row">
  <td class="col-xs-6"></td >
  <td class="col-xs-6"></td >
  <td class="col-xs-6"></td >
  <td class="col-xs-6"></td >
  <td class="col-xs-6"></td >
  <td class="col-xs-6"></td >
  <td class="col-xs-12"></td >
  <td class="col-xs-12"></td >
</table>
```

This is just a quick example of the sort of code that would be required but without seeing you're code its hard to get a proper idea

Comment: I have given the classes which you said but on resize it is not working

Comment: Have you got a class row, that encapsulates the whole table? Edited answer to show this

Comment: Thanks Smithy but this was not working, I have used ngResposiveCss , but I got a issue in that. Could you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674121/responsive-table-but-need-to-edit-few-rows-style-on-resize