# Responsive table but need to edit few rows style on resize

Tags: c#, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Page is something like this
[image]

Now on resize it is changing to something like this:
[image]

But I need last two rows to use the complete space e.g. Result should start from the below of Email, kind of Centre approach.

Table Html is

```
            <table class="responsive">

                <thead>
                        <tr>
<th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=Id&amp;grid-dir=0">Employe Id</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-filter" data-filterdata="[]" data-name="Name" data-type="System.String" data-widgetdata="null"><span class="grid-filter-btn" title="Filter this column"></span></div><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=Name&amp;grid-dir=0">Name</a></div></th><th class="grid-header"><div class="grid-header-title"><a href="?grid-column=Email&amp;grid-dir=0">Email</a></div></th><th class="grid-header" style="width:80px;"><div class="grid-header-title"><span></span></div></th><th class="grid-header" style="width:80px;"><div class="grid-header-title"><span></span></div></th>    </tr>

                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr class="grid-row ">
<td class="grid-cell" data-name="Id">1</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="Name">XyZ</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="Email">XyZ@gmail.com</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name=""><a href='#'>Result </a><a href='#'>Output </a><a href='#'>Error</a></td><td class="grid-cell" data-name=""><img alt='img1' src='' ></img><img alt='img2' src='' ></img><img alt='img3' src='' ></img></td>    </tr>
    <tr class="grid-row ">
<td class="grid-cell" data-name="Id">2</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="Name">XyZ2</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="Email">XyZ@gmail.com</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name=""><a href='#'>Result </a><a href='#'>Output </a><a href='#'>Error</a></td><td class="grid-cell" data-name=""><img alt='img1' src='' ></img><img alt='img2' src='' ></img><img alt='img3' src='' ></img></td>    </tr>
    <tr class="grid-row ">
<td class="grid-cell" data-name="Id">3</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="Name">Romonov</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name="Email">XyZ@gmail.com</td><td class="grid-cell" data-name=""><a href='#'>Result </a><a href='#'>Output </a><a href='#'>Error</a></td><td class="grid-cell" data-name=""><img alt='img1' src='' ></img><img alt='img2' src='' ></img><img alt='img3' src='' ></img></td>    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

jQuery is :

```
;(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.ngResponsiveTables = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
        smallPaddingCharNo: 5,
        mediumPaddingCharNo: 10,
        largePaddingCharNo: 15
        },
        $selElement = this,
        ngResponsiveTables = {
            opt: '',
            dataContent: '',
            globalWidth: 0,
        init: function(){
            this.opt = $.extend( defaults, options );
            ngResponsiveTables.targetTable();
        },
        targetTable: function(){
            var that = this;
            $selElement.find('tr').each(function(){
                $(this).find('td').each(function(i, v){
                    that.checkForTableHead( $(this), i );
                    $(this).addClass('tdno' + i);
                });
            });
        },
        checkForTableHead: function(element, index){
            if( $selElement.find('th').length ){
                this.dataContent = $selElement.find('th')[index].textContent;
            }else{
                this.dataContent = $selElement.find('tr:first td')[index].textContent;
            }
            // This padding is for large texts inside header of table
            // Use small, medium and large paddingMax values from defaults to set-up offsets for each class
            if( this.opt.smallPaddingCharNo > $.trim(this.dataContent).length ){
                element.addClass('small-padding');            
            }else if( this.opt.mediumPaddingCharNo > $.trim(this.dataContent).length ){
                element.addClass('medium-padding');            
            }else{
                element.addClass('large-padding');              
            }
            element.attr('data-content', this.dataContent);
        }
    };

    $(function(){
        ngResponsiveTables.init();
    });
        return this;
    };

}( jQuery ));
```

css is :

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    /* CSS Responsive table */
    table.responsive,
    table.responsive thead,
    table.responsive tbody,
    table.responsive th,
    table.responsive td,
    table.responsive tr {
        display: block;
    }

        table.responsive thead tr {
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        table.responsive tr {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        table.responsive td {
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%;
        }

            table.responsive td:before {
                position: absolute;
                top: 6px;
                left: 6px;
                width: 40%;
                padding-right: 10px;
                text-align: left;
                word-wrap: break-word;
                color: skyblue;
                font-weight:bold;
            }

        table.responsive tr:first-child {
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        table.responsive td:before {
            content: attr(data-content);
            height: 50px;
        }

        table.responsive td.small-padding {
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

        table.responsive td.medium-padding {
            padding-top: 15px;
            padding-bottom: 15px;
        }

        table.responsive td.large-padding {
            padding-top: 25px;
            padding-bottom: 25px;
        }
}
```

I have used ngResponsiveCss.

Can you please guide what should I edit in this.

Comment: that is allot of javascript for a very simple task, why dont you use Media Queries? Media Queries are simple CSS classes that can be swapped for different screen sizes.

Comment: @MarkHomer, can you please help me to edit this to make it usable as per the requirements

Comment: I am not going to solve the problem for you, do some research: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries gives you details of Media Queries not hard